# Calculating strings date time

Tags: bash

I have two variables:

```
dateTimeNow=$(date -d 'now' +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
tokenExpireDate=$(date -d 'now + 25 minutes' +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I want to check if $tokenExpireDate <= than $dateTimeNow

Something like this

```
if [[ "${tokenExpireDate}" <= "${dateTimeNow}" ]]; then echo "hi"; fi
```

I got:

```
-bash: syntax error in conditional expression
-bash: syntax error near `"${dateTimeNow}"'
```

Comment: `help test` - look for `<=` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you could compare strings like that, but you can compare the total seconds of the 2 dates:

```
dateTimeNow=$(date -d 'now' +%s)
tokenExpireDate=$(date -d 'now + 25 minutes' +%s)
```

And then use the `-le` and `-ge` operators for comparison:

```
if [[ ${tokenExpireDate} -ge ${dateTimeNow} ]]; then echo "hi"; fi
```

Comment: Bash 4.2+ has; `printf -v dateTimeNow '%(%s)T'; tokenExpireDate=$((dateTimeNow + 25 * 60))`, to capture both timestamps without spawning a sub-shell or running an external tool.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `<=` operator, just `<` and `>`.

Since `<=` is the same as `not >`, you can simply reverse the comparison and invert the test.

```
if [[ !("${tokenExpireDate}" > "${dateTimeNow}") ]]; then echo "hi"; fi
```